# Calculate and display percentage of a boolean column, and date ranges across a set of columns

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

This is what a few rows looks like in my dataset in Tableau

| Country | State | Date | Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INDIA | MH | 2023/01/01 | True |
| INDIA | MH | 2023/01/02 | False |
| INDIA | KA | 2023/01/02 | False |
| USA | OR | 2023/01/01 | True |
| USA | NY | 2023/01/15 | False |

I want to create a Tableau dashboard that shows a success ratio for a given Country, State and Year. Year is a filter that the user can choose. I also want to show a column that shows date ranges of country and state for a given year, where success was false. Something like

| Country | State | Success Ratio | Failure dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INDIA | MH | 73% | 01/15-03/20, 04/01-04/15, 05/07, 06/08 |
| INDIA | KA | 73% | 02/15-03/25, 04/01, 04/25-05/07, 06/09 |
| US | WA | 25% | 05/25-08/28, 09/12 |
| US | NY | 48% | 11/01 - 12/20, 12,24 |

Success ratio is defined as percentage of success datapoints over total datapoints for that country  and state in that year. I'm using Tableau Desktop, and very new to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH to create two tables (one with success ratio and one with failure dates) and join these to get the desired result. This can be a view tableau looks at.  example below

```
with a as  (
select country , state, STRING_AGG(Date, ', ') as [Failure] from 
YourTable where success = 'false'
group by country , state
),
b as (
select country 
, state
,  (sum (case when success = 'true' then 1 else 0 end)/ cast(count(1) as 
decimal(3,2)))* 100  as [Ratio]
from YourTable
group by country , state
)
select b.*, a.Failure from b left join a on a.country = b.country and a.State = b.State
```

Comment: My recommendation is to first try to use Tableau features (and let Tableau generate the SQL) before writing hand crafted SQL. This gives you flexibility and is easier to maintain - although you might have to learn some Tableau features, like sets, LOD calcs, table calcs, that effort will pay off. I'm not saying that there is never a reason to write hand crafted SQL, just that the cases where you need to do that are relatively rare.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a calculated field called **Success_Ratio** as

```
SUM(INT([SUCCESS])) / COUNT([My Input Table Name])
```

or equivalently

```
SUM(INT([SUCCESS])) / COUNT("*")
```

Then set the default number format for your new field to be a percentage (i.e. right click on the field in the data pane left margin and choose Default Properties->Number Format)

This works because the type conversion function INT() maps True to one and False to zero.

The easiest way to show the failure dates is with another viz or table, either using a filter action on a dashboard to let people drill down to a list of dates, or using a viz in a tooltip. There are ways to rollup a comma separated list like you showed, but they take more work than simply using a separated viz to drill from down a selected state to show a list of failure dates, each on its own row.